# How to get type of media in QMediaPlayer (video or audio)?

Tags: qt, qmediaplayer

I want to draw image in video widget when video is not playing. But I don't know how to check if media is not  video. The problem is that source file extension can be mp3, but it is video.

QMediaPlayer::isVideoAvailable doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I've solved by checking

```
QMediaPlayer::isVideoAvailable()
```

But, as in your case, it may not work if checked too early.

To be sure, you should connect to the signal:

```
QMediaPlayer::videoAvailableChanged(bool videoAvailable)
```

And then show the image if videoAvailable == false.